# download csv report from msgraph api

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, websphere-8

Using Java 8, on Websphere 8.x .  Trying to grab a audit report from the MS Graph API (`/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period='D7')` end point) to do things like report last user login activity, etc.

Generating the OAuth token, etc. all works fine, and I can grab the `302 redirect` URL successfully and that lets me download the CSV report file from the browser, using `postman` or `wget`, PHP's `file_get_contents` etc.

Working from home just using a Java 8 command line app, the following code grabs the file fine.  If I copy paste the code to my work machine and call it via Websphere web app, I get an IOException with the message "connection reset"  (note - NOT reset by peer!).  I've added the SSL certificate for `reports.office.com` and have added the Apache Commons CSV lib/jar to my build and class paths.

Suggestions on how to further debug for fix this are appreciated.

```
    String targetUrl = "https://reportsncu.office.com/data/v1.0/download?token=eyJ...*snip*...gFCg";
    try {
        InputStream input = new URL(targetUrl).openStream();
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(input);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(r);
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            String user = record.get(1);
            String lastActive = record.get(5);
            if (user.equals("user@example.com")) {
                System.out.println(user + " last active " + lastActive);
            }
        }
        r.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException: "+ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

"Interesting" part of the StackTrace() indicates there may be something SSL going on, but it isn't the usual "forgot to import webserver cert into websphere config" error I usually see when first connecting to an API service, etc.

```
SystemErr R java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
SystemErr R at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:220)
SystemErr R at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:79)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:182)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:883)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:969)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:680)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:859)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSSocket.startHandshake(WSSocket.java:414)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:16)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:44)
SystemErr R at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1561)
SystemErr R at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1489)
SystemErr R at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:93)
SystemErr R at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1057)
```

Comment: Does the IOException have a cause that provides more context? If you just do an ex.printStackTrace() - does that provide any more of a hint? Smells like it might be a firewall/network/infrastructure/certificate issue.

Comment: @NotaJD it may be ssl related... even though it isn't the usual SSL errors I see when I forget to import a webserver's cert into my dev websphere.  Question edited to include interesting part of stacktrace

Comment: Ah ha - are you using the same SDK version on both your home and work systems *AND* are the policy files the same? You might need to update your policy files... https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liaag/wascrypt/l0wscry00_updatejcepolicyfile.htm

Comment: @NotaJD thanks. i'll need to bug my tech help on Monday about it - can you tell me what exactly needs changing?  Connecting to new API providers usually just involves me importing the cert in the keystore section of the websphere admin console... and I've only been using ws for a few months... loong time LAMP stack admin/dev though

Comment: The stack trace you posted brought back horrible memories of the IBM JDK :) I don't have anything specific that's public - but this help some! https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ec367703-7957-4249-9f0b-559c717c0c87

Comment: @NotaJD - thanks, helps tremendously. if you'll post it as an answer, I'll cheerfully accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report back if this doesn't help, @ivanivan!

The stack trace you posted brought back horrible memories of the IBM JDK :) I don't have anything specific that's public - but this help some! https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ec367703-7957-4249-9f0b-559c717c0c87